# How to remove and stop a thread based on its entry in a Listview/List?

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms

I have some code that starts a new thread every time a button is clicked. Each new thread draws a randomly colored circle in a random location in a primitive graphics engine and is added to a Listview. The link to this engine is https://github.com/NAIT-CNT/GDIDrawer.

I need to find a way to remove and abort a thread based on whatever Listview item the user clicks.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using GDIDrawer;
using System.Threading;

namespace ica7
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        CDrawer _gdi = new CDrawer();
        List<Thread> _threads = new List<Thread>();
        Random _rng = new Random();
        Point _coords;
        int _diameter;
        bool _isRunning;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _diameter = 10;
            _isRunning = true;
            btnStopThreads.Enabled = false;
        }


        private Color RandomColor()
        {
            return Color.FromArgb(_rng.Next(256), _rng.Next(256), _rng.Next(256));
        }

        private void DrawCircle(int diameter, Point coords, CDrawer gdi)
        {
            gdi.AddCenteredEllipse(coords, diameter, diameter, RandomColor());
        }

        private void btnStartThread_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnStopThreads.Enabled = true;
            Thread t = new Thread(() =>
            {
                int diameter = _diameter;
                while (_isRunning)
                {
                    _coords.X = _rng.Next(800);
                    _coords.Y = _rng.Next(600);
                    DrawCircle(diameter, _coords, _gdi);
                    Thread.Sleep(10);
                }
            });
            _threads.Add(t);
            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(t.ToString());
            lboxThreads.Items.Add(lvi);
            t.Start();
        }

        private void btnStopThreads_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _threads.ElementAt(lboxThreads.SelectedIndex).Abort();
            lboxThreads.Items.RemoveAt(lboxThreads.SelectedIndex);

        }

        private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _diameter = trackBar1.Value;
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            _threads.ForEach(x => x.Abort());
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the designer file, in case it's needed:

```
namespace ica7
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            this.btnStartThread = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.btnStopThreads = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.lboxThreads = new System.Windows.Forms.ListBox();
            this.trackBar1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar();
            this.lblTbMin = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.lblTbMax = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.trackBar1)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // btnStartThread
            // 
            this.btnStartThread.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaptionText;
            this.btnStartThread.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(9, 11);
            this.btnStartThread.Name = "btnStartThread";
            this.btnStartThread.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(121, 23);
            this.btnStartThread.TabIndex = 0;
            this.btnStartThread.Text = "Start a Thread";
            this.btnStartThread.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.btnStartThread.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnStartThread_Click);
            // 
            // btnStopThreads
            // 
            this.btnStopThreads.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaptionText;
            this.btnStopThreads.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(9, 40);
            this.btnStopThreads.Name = "btnStopThreads";
            this.btnStopThreads.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(121, 23);
            this.btnStopThreads.TabIndex = 1;
            this.btnStopThreads.Text = "Stop Selected Thread";
            this.btnStopThreads.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.btnStopThreads.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnStopThreads_Click);
            // 
            // lboxThreads
            // 
            this.lboxThreads.FormattingEnabled = true;
            this.lboxThreads.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(138, 11);
            this.lboxThreads.Name = "lboxThreads";
            this.lboxThreads.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(303, 134);
            this.lboxThreads.TabIndex = 2;
            // 
            // trackBar1
            // 
            this.trackBar1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(9, 69);
            this.trackBar1.Maximum = 50;
            this.trackBar1.Minimum = 10;
            this.trackBar1.Name = "trackBar1";
            this.trackBar1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(121, 45);
            this.trackBar1.TabIndex = 3;
            this.trackBar1.Value = 10;
            this.trackBar1.Scroll += new System.EventHandler(this.trackBar1_Scroll);
            // 
            // lblTbMin
            // 
            this.lblTbMin.AutoSize = true;
            this.lblTbMin.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 101);
            this.lblTbMin.Name = "lblTbMin";
            this.lblTbMin.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(19, 13);
            this.lblTbMin.TabIndex = 4;
            this.lblTbMin.Text = "10";
            // 
            // lblTbMax
            // 
            this.lblTbMax.AutoSize = true;
            this.lblTbMax.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(111, 101);
            this.lblTbMax.Name = "lblTbMax";
            this.lblTbMax.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(19, 13);
            this.lblTbMax.TabIndex = 5;
            this.lblTbMax.Text = "50";
            // 
            // timer1
            // 
            this.timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaptionText;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(453, 157);
            this.Controls.Add(this.lblTbMax);
            this.Controls.Add(this.lblTbMin);
            this.Controls.Add(this.trackBar1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.lboxThreads);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnStopThreads);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnStartThread);
            this.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaption;
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.FormClosed += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventHandler(this.Form1_FormClosed);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.trackBar1)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnStartThread;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnStopThreads;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ListBox lboxThreads;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar trackBar1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label lblTbMin;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label lblTbMax;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1;
    }
}
```

If there are superior ways of doing any of this, please let me know. This is my first foray into threads. This is homework.

Comment: Spawning a thread for each drawing is quite inefficient...

Comment: It's part of the assignment.

Comment: You aren't storing the thread in the listview. You're storing its string representation, which cannot be used to get the original thread back. You will need to store the actual thread somewhere, either in a separate list, or perhaps you could store it in the [`ListViewItem.Tag` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.tag?view=netframework-4.7.2) with each item.

Comment: @JohnWu that worked perfectly. One problem remains - if I wanted the threads to show up as the number they were created as in the Listview, how would I do that? Something to do with the Text property?

Comment: Yes, I would set the `Text` property to the thread's `ManagedThreadId`

Comment: Awesome. Worked again. Is there any way to get it start from 0 rather than 6? I assume it counts the threads used by Windows to run the program as well. I can see them in the Threads window in VS.

Comment: It isn't actually a counter; it's a unique ID, which happens to ascend, sometimes. There's no way to change it.

Comment: @Dumbassahedratron - Are you certain that the `CDrawer` is thread-safe and it can be run from a non-UI thread?

Comment: Also, you cannot call `_threads.ElementAt(lboxThreads.SelectedIndex).Abort();` unless you are trying to crash out of your application. Calling `Thread.Abort()` can leave the run-time corrupted. You really need an alternative to make the threads end naturally.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions?